# Failover for Blob transfer in ActiveMq

Tags: activemq-classic

Is failover for blob transfer policy available in ActiveMQ ? I tried searching AMQ documentation but could not find any such thing. In case I want to use ActiveMQ's jetty server for file upload and I am using failover protocol with multiple hosts , how should I set Blob transfer policy ? We are using ActiveMQ 5.10.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably need a load balancer (or at least some sort of fail over "VIP" IP address) towards the HTTP server. HTTP does not behave the same way as OpenWire protocol that can deal with failover from client side.

Note that the fileserver in ActiveMQ is more or less a test/development thing. For real, high availability deployments, consider deploying that app in a load balanced/clustered Application server. Also, note that a fail over will lead to stranded messages, if the fileserver web apps does not share the same disk.

Consider backing your blob store with a shared network disk so that all nodes can see the same messages.

If you want something more out of the box, take a look at [Apache ActiveMQ Artemis](https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/large-messages.html#large-messages) that supports large messages a bit more native than ActiveMQ.